# Qt - qmake -project, qmake, what next?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `Qt` program. When I ran `qmake -project` and `qmake` it worked fine.

But, how can I run my program now?

Thanks.

Comment: More information needed - what platform are you developing on?

Comment: @laalto. I'm using `Windows 7 Enterprise`

Comment: Ok, when you've successfully built the app (`make` answers below), you'll end up with an .exe that you can run.

Answer (score 5):

[`make`](http://linuxhelp.blogspot.com/2006/01/creating-and-compiling-qt-projects-on.html) it, if you are using it in Linux.  Use [`nmake`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd9y37ha%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) if you are using it in Windows with MSVC, or `mingw32-make` if you are using the Qt SDK for Windows without MSVC.

Comment: or nmake on windows with msvc

Comment: @inflagranti, Yeah thanks.. I was about to add but just wanted to add it with a link to help a bit more.. :)

Comment: @inflagranti. It seems there should be a prameter going after `nmake`? As I got the following when using `nmake` alone: `C:\Users\avbder\Desktop\projects>nmake
'nmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: No, nmake will work by itself. However, the error message tells you that nmake could not be found. Did you add the msvc compiler stuff to your path, start a msvc console or executed the msvc batch file to setup the msvc environment. (and sorry for writing msvc so many times, sounds like a microsoft ad... ;))

Comment: @user588855, I assume you have one of the visual studio versions installed.. Look into Visual studio's installation folder and check for `nmake`.. Mostly will be available in some `bin` folder. Add that to `PATH` variable and open the command prompt and give `nmake` from the specified folder..

Comment: @liaK. I'm using `Qt Command Prompt`, how can I make `nmake` usable within it?

Comment: You need to use `mingw32-make` if you are using the Win32 Qt SDK install without a msvc install.

Answer (score 1):

qmake only makes a make file, so then you need to build it. i.e. 'make' or 'gmake' or VS or whatever